# Mod Rewrite with multiple parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to setup a rewrite rule so that any text in place of a subdomain will be parameter one and any text after the first forward slash will be parameter two but I'm struggling with regex and am unsure about rewrite terminology.

For example, if someone requested:

```
joebloggs.mydomain.com
```

I would like them to see:

```
mydomain.com/index.php?site=joebloggs
```

Also, if someone requested:

```
joebloggs.mydomain.com/contact
```

I would like them to see:

```
mydomain.com/index.php?site=joebloggs&page=contact
```

By "see" I mean see the page, rather than see the URL - it's a CMS-like project so you can probably see where I'm going with it. Also, I've worked out how to remove www. so that's not an issue :)

---

EDIT

Current .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L]

# Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.richardmjenkins.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://richardmjenkins.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite for site/page pair
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.richardmjenkins\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !p.php
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?([^/]*)$ p.php?s=%1&p=$2 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.richardmjenkins\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !p.php
RewriteRule ^$ p.php?s=%1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: if your problem solved, you must select one of answers for best answer

Answer (score 0):

**1.** In your host panel : add a subdomain with name : `*` for enable all subdomains

**2.** this is your htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +Followsymlinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?site=%1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?site=%1&page=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www)[^.]+)\.(mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?site=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www)[^.]+)\.(mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?site=%1&page=%2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Actually not quite it, it's not grabbing the second var :( current .htaccess is:

> RewriteEngine On
> 
> # Remove www
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> 
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ p.php?s=%1&p=$2 [QSA,L,NC]

The subdomain bit works but the second var is empty. I've tried by adding (.*) to capture the second variable but no luck. Any ideas? (PS can't get formatting to work, sorry!)

Comment: Your .htaccess doesn't look like what I have suggested in my answer. Pls try that and let me know.

Comment: That's because I tried it but it didn't quite work :) Currently I've got this: RewriteEngine On
# Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.richardmjenkins.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://richardmjenkins.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Rewrite for site/page pair
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.richardmjenkins\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !p.php
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?([^/]*)$ p.php?s=%1&p=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.richardmjenkins\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !p.php
RewriteRule ^$ p.php?s=%1 [QSA,L,NC]
Which breaks when a trailing slash is added to the URL. Know a fix?

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess by editing your question rather than comment which is almost impossible to read.

Comment: Good idea, done :)
Currently, I believe the slash is removed server-side without rewrite, but I'd like it to rewrite for SEO purposes. Ideally, to add a trailing slash if it's missing, but either would be good!